# Can we use Flask test_client() inside async function

Tags: python, flask, pytest, python-asyncio, httpx

I'm trying to test Flask REST-API end points with pytest using **test_client()**. But I'm getting an Error saying

```
> RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.
```

Can Anyone explain me why this happen and what is the solution to avoid this Error.

Test Functiob:

```
import pytest
from  unittest import mock

from flask import request
from app import create_app
from app.base.views import views

app = create_app()


async def save_token_(sugar, payload, instance, bool, domain_id):
    return {'valid':True}

payload = {
    "password": 'password', 
    "username": 'crm_admin',
    "grant_type": "password"
}

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_post_sugar_token(monkeypatch, aiohttp_client, loop):
    mock_save_token = mock.AsyncMock(name = "mock_save_token")
    mock_save_token.return_value = await save_token_(None, payload, 'domain.org', True, 89)
    monkeypatch.setattr(views, 'save_token', mock_save_token)

    await views.save_token(None, payload, 'domain.org', True, 9)
    assert mock_save_token.call_args_list == [mock.call(None, payload, 'domain.org', True, 89)]

    headers = {'Autherization': 'ehrdmek2492.fkeompvmw.04294002'}
    data = {
        'password': '12345',
        'key':'Hi',
        'instance': 'my.domain',
        'domain_id': 1
    }

    ##-# using test_client()
    client = app.test_client()
    res = client.post('/token/sugar/', data = data, headers = headers)

    assert res.status_code == 200
    assert res.content_type == 'application/json'
    assert res.json == {'valid':True}
# # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PakM7.png)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and opened a ticket on flask's github repo:
https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4375.
They kindly explained the issue and provided a workaround.

In short, flask can handle async views, and flask's test_client can be used in an async context, but you cannot use both at the same time.

Quoting from the github issue:

> The problem in this case is that the Flask codebase is not compatible with asyncio, so you cannot run the test client inside an asyncio loop. There is really nothing to gain from writing your unit test as an async test, since Flask itself isn't async.

Here's the workaround suggested, slightly re-adjusted for your example:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_post_sugar_token():
    # ... same code as before

    ##-# using test_client()
    def sync_test():
        with app.test_client() as client:
            res = client.post('/token/sugar/', data = data, headers = headers)
            assert res.status_code == 200
            assert res.content_type == 'application/json'
            assert res.json == {'valid':True}

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of [0xf10413](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17647022/0xf10413) I created a small wrapper of the flask test client that is compatible with async pytests:

Flask app:

```py
import asyncio

from flask import Flask, jsonify


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    async def hello_world():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # mock something
        return jsonify("Hello, World!")

    return app
```

Test file:

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

import pytest
from werkzeug import Response
from flask.testing import FlaskClient

from main import create_app


T = TypeVar('T')


async def call(f: Callable[[], T]) -> T:
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(executor=None, func=f)


class AsyncTestClient(FlaskClient):
    """ A facade for the flask test client. """

    async def get(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        parent = super()
        return await call(lambda: parent.get(*args, **kwargs))

    async def post(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        parent = super()
        return await call(lambda: parent.post(*args, **kwargs))

    async def delete(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        parent = super()
        return await call(lambda: parent.delete(*args, **kwargs))

    async def put(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        parent = super()
        return await call(lambda: parent.put(*args, **kwargs))


@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    app = create_app()
    app.config.update({"TESTING": True})
    return app


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app) -> FlaskClient:
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture()
def async_client(app) -> AsyncTestClient:
    return AsyncTestClient(app, Response, True)


def test_sync(client):
    res = client.get('/')
    assert res.json == "Hello, World!"


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_async(async_client):
    res = await async_client.get('/')
    assert res.json == "Hello, World!"
```